# TypeScript function to check if type is not assignable to custom type

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example I have type:

```
type Fruits = 'apple' | 'lemon' | 'orange';
```

And I have some function like this:

```
const validateFruit = (value): boolean => {
  /// return true if value has type Fruits
}
```

Is there any solution to create this function?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/samchon/typia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use string enums instead you can achieve this more easily:

```
enum Fruits { apple = 'apple',  lemon = 'lemon',  orange = 'orange' }; 
const validateFruit = (value): value is Fruits => Fruits[value] !== undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an answer since I can't comment yet:

> This is a solution but not exact that I asked. Simply because at this case I need to duplicate types into array.

In addition to what Howard wrote: You could create the type based on the array. That way you wouldn't have to type the fruits in the array AND the type.

```
    const FRUITS_ARRAY = ['apple', 'lemon', 'banana'] as const
    type Fruits = typeof FRUITS_ARRAY[number]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32492692)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [type-guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)?

Something like below:

```
type Fruits = 'apple' | 'lemon' | 'orange';  

function isFruits(value: Fruits | any): value is Fruits {
    return ['apple', 'lemon', 'orange'].indexOf(value) > -1;
}

console.log(isFruits('dd'));
```

Comment: This is a solution but not exact that I asked. Simply because at this case I need to duplicate types into array.